# Open iCloud drive programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, settings, icloud, cloudkit

I'm using CloudKit in my app and I want to send the user to iCloud settings in case he/she hasn't enabled or set it up. I am currently using the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

But it opens the following:

[image]

So the user would have to go back and look for iCloud to set it up, how can I redirect the user directly to iCloud settings?

Comment: You can't Apple only allows you to open your apps settings.

Comment: @rckoenes not even the general settings?

Comment: No only your own app settings.